# In ReactJS, can you use a loop in Array.fill?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lambda

I'm from a C# background but am new to React and JS in general. I was wondering if there was a way to use lambda functions when declaring an array, for example:

```
this.state = {
arr: Array(9).fill( (i) => {<Foo index={i} />} ),
};
```

I'm trying to make an array of React.Components with ascending values in index, and was hoping this would be a viable option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not with `.fill()` alone, as it will just assign rather than invoke the function you give it.

```
Array(3).fill(() => {}); // [ function, function, function ]
```

You can use it along with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), however, to accomplish this. The iterator function you provide will be given the index as the 2nd argument (using `_` as a throwaway variable for the 1st).

```
Array(9).fill(0).map((_, i) => <Foo index={i} />)
```

Using both is necessary because `Array(9)` only assigns the array's `length`, leaving the indexes unassigned.

```
'length' in Array(9) // true
0 in Array(9) // false
```

While `.fill()` will work with unassigned indexes, `.map()` specifically will ignore them.

---

You can also use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) instead, which accepts the same iterator as `.map()`.

```
Array.from(Array(9), (_, i) => <Foo index={i} />)
```

Also, with it, the 1st argument doesn't necessarily have to be an `Array`:

```
Array.from({ length: 9 }, (_, i) => <Foo index={i} />)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great. I was trying to use map but didn't realise it would skip unassigned values in the array. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this:

```
this.state = {
  arr: new Array(5).map((emptyElement, index) => <Foo index={index} />);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
this.state = {
  arr: Array.from(Array(9), (value, index) => <Foo index={index} />)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be adding components to the state, [it's a good practice to put just serializable data in it](https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md#state). Also, components should be created inside `render()`.

Anyway, if you wanted to do something similar to create, let's say, an array of numbers, I'd do something like this:

```
this.state = {
    arr: Array(9).fill().map((v, i) => i),
};
```

Or, assuming those numbers always start at `0`:

```
this.state = {
    arr: [...Array(9).keys()],
};
```